# User not received confirmation code while signup and how to enable MFA for this case in aws-amplify-react-native

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, multi-factor-authentication

How can I know if the user received code while doing Auth.signUp in aws-amplify-react-native.

I need to track the user received code or not while registration of a new user. Does aws-amplify-react-native has any methods to track or show any message for the user in UI?

How can I know if the MFA is enabled or not that user in UI?

If it is not enable how can I will change to enable state.

Note: In my settings it is in optional state. So some users not received code while Auth.SignUp

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it based on the authentication challenge you receive when a user is successfully logged in. If the user is logged in for the first time I think initially you'll receive "NEW_PASSWORD_REQUIRED" and once the password is changed and If MFA is enabled you'll receive "SMS_MFA". You can change states or route the user based on the authentication challenge's. [Authentication Challenge](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_RespondToAuthChallenge.html)

Comment: I need to enable MFA while user signUp means registering as a new user

Comment: Here MFA is not enabled for me automatically